# Unicorn and copy_on_write_friendly?

Tags: debian, configuration, ruby, unicorn, sinatra

While researching Unicorn configuration options I came across this snippet..

```
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true
```

If I undertand correctly, it optimizes how Unicorn handles memory allocation and resource sharing between workers?

I use Unicorn to power my Sinatra application on server with Ruby 1.9.3. Are there any downsides to including the **copy_on_write_friendly** setting in my unicorn config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a configuration option, it's a Ruby code snippet that tells it to set copy_on_write_friendly if the GC object has that method.  For example, in ruby mainline 1.9.2p290:

```
1.9.2p290 :003 > GC.copy_on_write_friendly
NoMethodError: undefined method `copy_on_write_friendly' for GC:Module
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

The only Ruby interpreter that supports that option to my knowledge is Ruby Enterprise Edition.  There's a bit about it here: http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/faq.html

Comment: Ruby 2.0 also [has a copy-on-write friendly GC](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/3/23/why-you-should-be-excited-about-garbage-collection-in-ruby-2-0)

Comment: @NARKOZ But to be clear, Ruby 2.0’s implementation doesn’t include the method in question (and doesn’t need anything to enable COW).